# Error - cannot load such file headless

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a script, which has a line:

```
require 'headless'
```

There are several other gems that are working perfect in the same script, here's httpd error log:

```
:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require' 
:cannot load such file -- headless
```

What is wrong here? I can see that I'm missing something, under 
**/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/** there is no **core_ext** directory.
I'm just trying to move some scripts from an old server to a new server.

Comment: Hi, author of the gem here. Could you updae to version 2.2.2 and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Put `gem "headless"` in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

Comment: Thank you. But I get an error running bundle install: 
`There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: There was a Errno::ENOENT while loading headless.gemspec: 
No such file or directory - git ls-files from
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/headless-2.2.0/headless.gemspec:15:in ``'
. Bundler cannot continue.`

Comment: `rm -rf /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/headless-2.2.0` and retry your `bundle install`

Comment: Sorry, no luck. Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Comment: Sounds like you ran `bundle install` in the wrong directory then. You have to be in your app's root folder, the one that contains the `Gemfile`